# get location from drone video with command line tools

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, exif

How to extract location data from drone video (DJI Mavick Pro 2) by command line? I tried both ffprobe and exiftool, no result. But as for the videos shooted by Android phone all is well.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the drone's footage doesn't contain any location data, but if you convert the drone's logfile to CSV with a site such as [airdata](https://airdata.com/) you can get the geolocation and correlate it to your footage. I'm sure there are other sites that do this task for free, but I'm not sure what the original file format is.

Assuming the data is valid, you could use something such as [RaceRender](https://racerender.com/) to overlay the data. [Here](https://racerender.com/RR3/docs/HowTo-Datalogger.html) is the specific documentation for that task.

All will be well on with your Android-recorded footage as GPS data is saved in the file itself (if enabled, of course).